# Generating a List with A sublists and B elements in each sublist

Tags: python

for some reason

```
a=4
b=3

sublists=[]
p=0
while p<b:
    sublists.append(0)
    p+=1
list=[]
p=0
while p<a:
    list.append(sublists)
    p+=1
```

is not the same as:

```
list=[[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
```

although they print the same, but they don't work the same way... 
Can someone clarify if there is a difference between the lists, and which is it?

Comment: I could not find a difference. A problem might be that ``list`` is python keyword - use another variable name.

Comment: i used "list" in the example so you guys could understand easily the code.

Comment: if you use numpy `arr = np.zeros([a,b])`  will do the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, you're appending the *same* sublist four times to `list` (which is an unfortunate name because it also shadows the built-in name, but that's not pertinent to the problem here). So if you modify one of the sublists, you modify all of them.

In the second example, you create a list with four *identical but distinct* sublists.

At any rate, that code looks more like a C program than a Python script - you should read a [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html) to start learning the language as it's meant to be used.

The correct way to create an `a`*`b`-sized "matrix" with entries predefined to `0` is:

```
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 3
>>> matrix = [[0] * b for _ in range(a)]
>>> matrix
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: i used "list" in the example so you guys could understand easily the code.

Comment: Then how do i create four identical but distinct sublists in another way that's not in the second example?

Answer (score 0):

they are working same if youo simple print the `id` of each sublists

```
print map(id, list) #will print the id of all sublist
sublists[1] = 2
print sublists, list,
```

output:-

```
[0, 0, 0]
[3053888556L, 3053888556L, 3053888556L, 3053888556L]
[0, 2, 0] [[0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0]]
>>>
```